# How to bind a dependency property to a window resource in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, dependency-properties

Suppose I have a context menu as a window resource:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ContextMenu 
        x:Shared="false"
        x:Key="ContextMenu">
        <MenuItem Header="{??}" />
    </ContextMenu>
</Window.Resources>
```

And I want to bind `MenuItem.Header` to a dependency property called `MenuItemHeader` on the window. What should `{??}` be and what should the code behind in the window class look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could name the window and reference it

```
<Window Name="Window" ...>
```

```
<MenuItem Header="{Binding MyDp, Source={x:Reference Window}}"...>
```

`MyDp` being the property. If you don't know how to define a dependency property read [the overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx).

*(I would use `Source` and [`x:Reference`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee795380.aspx) as [`ElementName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.elementname.aspx) usually does not work in disconnected places like `ContextMenus`)*